# this code is not working for {"parses", "parsecs"}

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
bool letterCheck(vector<string> arr)
{
    int b=0;
    int l1=arr[0].length();
    int l2=arr[1].length();
    for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<l2;j++)
        {
            if(tolower(arr[1][i])==tolower(arr[0][j]))
            b++;
        }
    }
    if(b<arr[1].length())
        return false;
    else return true;
}


int main()
{
    vector <string> v={"parses", "parsecs"};
    cout<<letterCheck(v);
    return 0;
}
```

**It is a program that accepts an array of two strings and checks if the letters in the second string are present in the first string.**

**Examples:**
letterCheck(["trances", "nectar"]) ➞ true

letterCheck(["compadres", "DRAPES"]) ➞ true

letterCheck(["parses", "parsecs"]) ➞ false

**This program is working for above given pairs.It return true for {"parses", "parsecs"} but it should return false.** 
**Can anybody tell me ,what is the problem in the code and what can i do to remove this problem??**

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger? If you do, does it behave as you expect?

Comment: You can shortcut all of this by returning `false` if the lengths are not equal, and then afterwards return `false` as soon as you find a pair of elements that are not the same character (after conversion to lowercase)

Comment: As an aside, this condition is unnecessarily checked twice in your loop: `if(tolower(arr[0][i])==tolower(arr[1][j]))`

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program step by step? This is what I do in 2nd step. (First step is to stare a while on it. Sometimes it helps, sometimes I have to fall back to debugging.)

Comment: Another aside: If you expect exactly two elements, make your parameter reflect that. Right now it can take 0, 1, 2, or a million elements. For the 0 and 1 values, you have UB

Comment: Reformat your code to make it easy to read. Currently, it is all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you try to count matching characters to see if all characters in the second string have a match in the first string. However, as there are duplicate characters in the first string the computation goes wrong: the presence of two `’s’` makes `b` bigger than you want it to be. You could break out of the loop once you found a character to avoid the issue.

As an aside, passing unchecked `char` to `tolower()` can get you undefined behavior: on most platforms `char` is signed but there is a precondition on `tolower()` which requires that arguments are nin-negative or `EOF`.

Also, the result of `b < arr[1].length()` is a `bool` (although it needs ro be inverted): there is no need to write a fancy condition to turn it into a Boolean value.